# Selenium and XPath. Can't find an element in a page (Instagram) even though it looks like I have the correct path. Flex element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, flexbox

I'm doing a webscraping course on Selenium. The overall objective is to scrape the photos on this page (https://www.instagram.com/dataminer2060/). The sub-objective I'm stuck on is scraping the number of posts (currently 37).

[image: 1st inspect element]
[image: 2nd inspect element]

My code is below. It all works to login to Instagram, get past the pop ups. The bit I'm struggling with is `def(scroll_down)` . I'm getting an unable to locate element error.

I suspect this is because this a flex element but I don't know how to navigate those yet.

Any help would be much appreciated

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

#to stop Selenium automatically closing

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

class App:
    def __init__(self, username='my.username', password='mypassword', target_username='dataminer2060',
                 path='/Users/MyUser/Desktop/instaPhotos'): 
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.target_username = target_username
        self.path = path
        self.service = Service('/Users/MyUser/Documents/Python/chromedriver')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=self.service)
        self.error = False
        self.main_url = 'https://www.instagram.com'
        self.driver.get(self.main_url)
        sleep(3)

        self.log_in()
        sleep(3)
        self.open_target_profile()
        sleep(3)
        self.scroll_down()

#HERE IS WHERE I'M STUCK

    def scroll_down(self):
        no_of_posts = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='g47SY lOXF2']")
        no_of_posts = str(no_of_posts.text)
        print(no_of_posts)
        input('stop for now')

#BELOW WORKS

    def open_target_profile(self):
        search_bar = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search']")
        search_bar.send_keys(self.target_username)
        target_profile_url = self.main_url + "/" + self.target_username + "/"
        self.driver.get(target_profile_url)
        sleep(3)

    def log_in(self):
        cookies = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Only Allow Essential Cookies')]")
        cookies.click()
        sleep(1)
        login_details = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Phone number, username or email address']")
        login_details.send_keys('my.username')
        sleep(2)
        password = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Password']")
        password.send_keys('mypassword')
        sleep(2)
        login_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Log In']")
        login_button.click()
        sleep(3)
        save_info = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Save information']")
        save_info.click()
        sleep(2)
        not_now2 = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Not Now']")
        not_now2.click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
```

I have tried that XPATH, the one for the div parent and the full XPath. I'm expecting to be able to find the element which contains the text with no. of posts.

Comment: Update the question with relevant HTML code and full error stack trace.

Comment: Also, I don't see any web element with this xpath `//span[@class='g47SY lOXF2']` at my end. May be cause it's getting dynamically generated. Which element is that?

Comment: Ah, may have made a rookie error. 

span class="g47SY "

I don't know where I got the added extra. Went over this multiple times but somehow it slipped through. Apologies, and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Made an error. `<span class="g47SY ">37</span>` Somehow I added extra code in the class field in my original code.

Comment: Is this a solution to the question?

Comment: Yes. That clears the error.